# Including column improves query performance SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

A query performance is being affected if a column is included or not, but the weird thing is that it affects positive (reduce time execution) if the column is included.

The query includes a few joins to a view, some tables and tabled valued functions like the next:

```
SELECT 
    v1.field1, t2.field2
FROM 
    view v1 WITH (nolock)
INNER JOIN 
    table t1 WITH (nolock) ON v.field1 = t1.field1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 t2 WITH (nolock) ON t2.field2 = t1.field2
INNER JOIN 
    function1(@param) f1 ON f1.field3 = t2.field3
WHERE 
    (v.date1 = @param OR v.date2 = @param)
```

The thing is if I include within the `select` a `varchar(200) not null` column which is part of the view (it is not indexed in the original table or the view, and it's not part of a constraint), the query performance is X seconds, but if I don't include it then the performance ups to 4X seconds, which is a lot of difference just for including a column; so the query with the best performance will be like:

```
SELECT 
    v1.field1, t2.field2, v1.fieldWhichAffectsPerformance
    view v1 WITH (nolock)
INNER JOIN 
    table t1 WITH (nolock) ON v.field1 = t1.field1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 t2 WITH (nolock) ON t2.field2 = t1.field2
INNER JOIN 
    function1(@param) f1 ON f1.field3 = t2.field3
WHERE 
    (v.date1 = @param OR v.date2 = @param)
```

It's mandatory to remove the column which improves the query performance, but without affecting in a negative way the actual performance. Any ideas?

EDIT: as suggested i've reviewed the execution plan, and the query without the column runs an extra hash match (left outer join) and uses index scan which cost a lot of CPU instead index seek which are the plan in the query with the column included. how can I remove the column without affecting the performance? any ideas?

Comment: Post the execution plan with and with the column in select. Make sure the statistics are up to date..

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: no sorting are used

Answer (score 0):

Optimizers are complicated.  Without query plans, there is only speculation.
You need to look at the query plans to get a real answer.

One possibility is the order of processing.  The `select` could equivalently be written as:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t2.field2
```

because the `on` condition specifies that columns in the two tables are the same.  The optimizer my recognize that the `or` prevents the use of indexes on the view (which is probably not applicable anyway).  So, instead of scanning the view, it decides to scan `table1` and then bring in the view.

By including an additional column in the `select`, you are pushing the optimizer to scan the view -- and this might be the better execution plan.

This is all hypothetical, but it gives a mechanism on how your observed timings could happen.